# Vue format date from DD-MM-YYYY to MM-DD-YYYY

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue Js. I have added dropdown date using `vue-date-dropdown`. Currently the format for date dropdown is DD-MM-YYYY, is there a way to change it to MM-DD-YYYY?

Package link for `vue-date-dropdown` = https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-date-dropdown

**My View**

```html
<b-form-group>
    <date-dropdown default="1993.02.27" min="1940" max="2020" :months-names="months" :format="'MM.DD.YYYY'" v-model="date_of_birth" id="dateDropdownDesign">
    </date-dropdown> 
    /** i tried to use :format date option , but it did not work **/
</b-form-group>
```

This is my image for date dropdown right now. It's displayed as DD MM YYYY format. Is there a way to change this UI code into MM DD YYYY format ?

[image]

Here is my code uploaded on `jsfiddle`

https://jsfiddle.net/ujjumaki/5pbzf012/2/

Comment: A working JSFiddle would be much more preferable

Comment: I would suggest choosing a different component. Any _"date picker"_ that returns a string instead of an actual `Date` object is just ridiculous

Comment: You cannot do what you want with that component. Look at the [source code](https://github.com/yangirov/vue-date-dropdown/blob/master/src/DateDropdown.vue); the template is hard-coded to show _"day - month - year"_. Pick a different component or fork this one and create your own version

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use something like https://vcalendar.io/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the moment and change date to any format:

`moment(this.date_of_birth, "DD.MM.YYYY").format("MM.DD.YYYY")`

like this :

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <date-dropdown
      default="1993.02.27"
      min="1940"
      max="2020"
      :months-names="months"
      :format="'MM.DD.YYYY'"
      v-model="date_of_birth"
      id="dateDropdownDesign"
    >
    </date-dropdown>
    /** i tried to use :format date option , but it did not work **/
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import DateDropdown from "vue-date-dropdown";
import moment from "moment";

export default {
  components: {
    DateDropdown,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      date_of_birth: "",
      new_date_of_birth: "",
      months: "",
    };
  },
  watch: {
    date_of_birth() {
      this.new_date_of_birth = moment(this.date_of_birth, "DD.MM.YYYY").format("MM.DD.YYYY");
      console.log(this.date_of_birth);
      console.log(this.new_date_of_birth);
    },
    months() {
      console.log(this.months);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: may be I was not clear. Date dropdown for UI displays as DD MM YYYY. Is there a way to change datedropdown into MM DD YYYY, as to display.