# Vue callback updates data but 3rd party component fails to re-render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

[Vue Date Dropdown](https://github.com/yangirov/vue-date-dropdown#readme)'s value should be updated when `conditions` is changed. Currently, the `watch` successfully updates `selectedDate` but fails to re-render `date-dropdown`.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <div>{{selectedDate}}</div> <-- this value is updated after getFilter()
      <date-dropdown default="1995-01-10" v-model="selectedDate"/> <-- this component holds old/default value: 1995-01-10
      <b-button @click="getFilter()" variant="primary">update</b-button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    import DateDropdown from "vue-date-dropdown";
    const SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:9000';
  const instance = axios.create({
      baseURL: SERVER_URL,
      timeout: 1000
  });

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
        DateDropdown
    },
    props: {
    },
    data () {
      return {
        selectedDate: '',
        filter: {
          name: 'Filter22With2Conditions',
          conditions: [
              { type: 'date', clause: 'until', data: '02.02.1990' },
          ]
        }
...
    watch: {
      filter: function () {
          this.selectedDate = this.filter.conditions[0].data;
      }
    },

    methods: {
        getFilter: function() {
            let self = this;
            instance.get('/api/filters?name=Filter22With2Conditions')
                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log('getFilter:response: ' + JSON.stringify(response.data))
                    self.filter = response.data;
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log('getFilter: error: '  + error)
                    self.errors.push(error);
                })
        },
...
}
```

Comment: [I've seen that component before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61994592/vue-format-date-from-dd-mm-yyyy-to-mm-dd-yyyy) and it's not a good one. Any date-picker that doesn't consume or produce a `Date` instance is not worth using IMO

Comment: It is required by stakeholders to use similar 3 dropdowns to select a date. Any good alternatives?

Comment: read https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components and look at the source of the component  https://github.com/yangirov/vue-date-dropdown/blob/master/src/DateDropdown.vue ... as you can see, there is no `value` prop